# List.stream, Объясните как работает этот код

Tags: java

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 7, 11, 2, 5, 7, 11);
    int a = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y);
    int b = list.stream().max((x, y) -> x > y ? x : y).get();
    int c = list.parallelStream().reduce(8, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y);
    int d = list.stream().reduce(11, (x, y) -> x < y ? x : y);
    int e = list.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
    int f = list.stream().max(Integer::max).get();
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что делает каждая строчка кода. И почему получается такой ответ (11, 8, 11, 2, 11, 8)

Comment: А код работает вообще?

Answer (score 3):

**a**

> int a = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y);

В этом случае отрабатывает обычный редьюсер. Если кратко, то происходит следующее:

1. Аккумулятор инициализируется начальнм значением (Integer.MIN_VALUE в данном случае)
2. Для каждого элемента из `list` применяется функция переданная 2-м параметром. В нее передается значение аккумулятора и текущий элемент, после чего в аккумулятор сохраняется результат выполнения функции
3. В конце `reduce` возвращает значение аккумулятора

В Вашем случае вызовы редьюсера будут примерно такими:

```
(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 8) -> Integer.MIN_VALUE > 8 ? //возвращается 8
(8, 2) -> 8 > 2 // возвращается 8
(8, 7) -> 8 > 7 // возвращается 8
(8, 11) -> 8 > 11 // возвращается 11
(11, 2) -> 11 > 2 // возвращается 11
(11, 5) -> 11 > 5 // возвращается 11
(11, 7) -> 11 > 7 // возвращается 11
(11, 11) -> 11 > 11  // возвращается 11 и присваивается переменной a
```

Важно заметить, что разных версях Java порядок вызовов может быть другим, поскольку в документации он не определен

Больше информации по Stream.reduce можно найти в [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), либо поискать что-то в интернете

**b**

> int b = list.stream().max((x, y) -> x > y ? x : y).get();

в метод `max` передается компаратор, который сравнивает 2 аргумента и возвращает число, которое интерпретируется следующим образом:

- *ноль*: оба аргумента равны
- *положительное число*: 1-й аргумент **больше**, чем 2-й
- *отрицательное число*: 1-й аргумент **меньше**, чем 2-й

В джавадоках и различных источниках в интернете можно найти больше информации на эту тему.

В Вашем случае `max` берет 2 числа из `list`, и считает, что 1-е из них большее (в данном случае это 8), поскольку компаратор `(x, y) -> x > y ? x : y` всегда возвращает положительное число для элементов из `list`. Далее компаратор последовательно вызывается для текущего максимального и всех остальных элементов.

Стоит отметить, что в документации не определено, какой элемент будет браться 1-м и в каком порядке он будет сравниваться с остальными. В данном случае похоже, что первым взялся элемент `8` и делее он передавался 1-м параметром в вызовы компаратора, поэтому в результате `map` вернул `8`. Теоретически в других версиях Java это поведение может поменяться

**c**

> int c = list.parallelStream().reduce(8, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y);

По сути то же самое, что и для `int a = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y)`, только с другим начальным значением аккумулятора и параллельным стримом

**d**

> int d = list.stream().reduce(11, (x, y) -> x < y ? x : y);

То же, что и для `int a = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y)` только с другим начальным значением и поиском минимального вместо максимального значения

**e**

> int e = list.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();

Аналогично `int b = list.stream().max((x, y) -> x > y ? x : y).get();`, только используется компаратор, который правильно сравнивает целые числа числа

**f**

> int f = list.stream().max(Integer::max).get();

По сути это то же самое, что и `int b = list.stream().max((x, y) -> x > y ? x : y).get();` поскольку `Integer::max` внутри делает практически то же самое, что и `(x, y) -> x > y ? x : y`